# Does coding towards an interface rather then an implementation imply a performance hit?

Tags: performance, oop, interface

In day to day programs I wouldn't even bother thinking about the possible performance hit for coding against interfaces rather than implementations. The advantages largely outweigh the cost. So please no generic advice on good OOP.

Nevertheless in [this](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/30645/173406.aspx#173406) post, the designer of the XNA (game) platform gives as his main argument to not have designed his framework's core classes against an interface that it would imply a performance hit. Seeing it is in the context of a game development where every fps possibly counts, I think it is a valid question to ask yourself.

Does anybody have any stats on that? I don't see a good way to test/measure this as don't know what implications I should bear in mind with such a game (graphics) object.

Comment: Your question is still valid but you are misquoting the guy. He is saying that providing the interfaces *merely for providing mocks for unit testing* wasn't worth the performance hit. Which I can see his point.

Comment: I don't know. How much of a perf hit would it serve? What is it worth to you to be able to test something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces generally imply a few hits to performance (this however may change depending on the language/runtime used):

1. Interface methods are usually implemented via a virtual call by the compiler.  As another user points out, these can not be inlined by the compiler so you lose that potential gain.  Additionally, they add a few instructions (jumps and memory access) at a minimum to get the proper PC in the code segment.
2. Interfaces, in a number of languages, also imply a graph and require a DAG (directed acyclic graph) to properly manage memory.  In various languages/runtimes you can actually get a memory 'leak' in the managed environment by having a cyclic graph.  This imposes great stress (obviously) on the garbage collector/memory in the system.  Watch out for cyclic graphs!
3. Some languages use a COM style interface as their underlying interface, automatically calling AddRef/Release whenever the interface is assigned to a local, or passed by value to a function (used for life cycle management).  These AddRef/Release calls can add up and be quite costly.  Some languages have accounted for this and may allow you to pass an interface as 'const' which will not generate the AddRef/Release pair automatically cutting  down on these calls.

Here is a small example of a cyclic graph where 2 interfaces reference each other and neither will automatically be collected as their refcounts will always be greater than 1.

```
interface Parent {
  Child c;
}

interface Child {
  Parent p;
}

function createGraph() {
  ...
  Parent p = ParentFactory::CreateParent();
  Child c = ChildFactory::CreateChild();

  p.c = c;
  c.p = p;      
  ...  // do stuff here

  // p has a reference to c and c has a reference to p.  
  // When the function goes out of scope and attempts to clean up the locals
  // it will note that p has a refcount of 1 and c has a refcount of 1 so neither 
  // can be cleaned up (of course, this is depending on the language/runtime and
  // if DAGS are allowed for interfaces).  If you were to set c.p = null or
  // p.c = null then the 2 interfaces will be released when the scope is cleaned up.
}
```

Comment: although I won't pretend to understand it all, I see an educated answer. Time for some reasearch

Comment: Can you give an example of how to create a cyclic graph? Pseudo code perhaps?

Comment: Doesn't the GC check if the ref to Parent/Child is to an object that is also marked for Garbage Check?
But I could see how such a check would have a hard limit on deepness for performance's sake.
I don't have hard facts on that but I would believe that the .net GC would have saves for such a thing.

Comment: This post is not specific to a language that implements a GC.  Also, in heterogeneous systems such as .NET, you are allowed to cross managed/unmanaged boundaries which could complicate the graph nodes ref counting system.

Answer (score 6):

Coding to an interface is always going to be easier, simply because interfaces, if done right, are much simpler. Its palpably easier to write a correct program using an interface.

And as the old maxim goes, its easier to make a correct program run fast than to make a fast program run correctly.

So program to the interface, get everything working and *then* do some profiling to help you meet whatever performance requirements you may have.

Comment: But I didn't get to design the XNA framework, so there is no interface available..

Comment: So in that specific case you have no choice, so any comparison is moot.

Comment: I'm not asking which is best, I'm asking if an interface does imply a perf hit. And if so, what magnitude are we talking about?

Comment: The only way you'll get a definitive answer is to code up two ways of doing it and profile them.

Answer (score 3):

First I'd say that the common conception is that programmers time is usually more important, and working against implementation will probably force much more work when the implementation changes.

Second with proper compiler/Jit I would assume that working with interface takes a ridiculously small amount of extra time compared to  working against the implementation itself.
Moreover, techniques like templates can remove the interface code from running.

Third to quote Knuth : "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."
So I'd suggest coding well first, and only if you are sure that there is a problem with the Interface, only then I would consider changing.

Also I would assume that if this performance hit was true, most games wouldn't have used an OOP approach with C++, but this is not the case, this [Article](http://www.gamearchitect.net/Articles/WhyC++.html) elaborates a bit about it.

It's hard to talk about tests in a general form, naturally a bad program may spend a lot of time on bad interfaces, but I doubt if this is true for all programs, so you really should look at each particular program.

Comment: For example Java's JIT will know when an interface has only one implementation loaded, so it can optimize the method calls to be non-virtual. Then if another implementation is loaded at runtime, the JIT will deoptimize the previously optimzied code and recompile it.

Answer (score 3):

[What Things Cost in Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx)

"There does not appear to be a significant difference in the raw cost of a static call, instance call, virtual call, or interface call."

It depends on how much of your code gets inlined or not at compile time, which can increase performance ~5x.

It also takes longer to code to interfaces, because you have to code the contract(interface) and then the concrete implementation.

But doing things the right way always takes longer.

Comment: Actually I believe that doing things the right way takes less time in the long run :).

Comment: Good for you, but my comment was in context of building it the first time, not maintenance

Answer (score 1):

I think object lifetime and the number of instances you're creating will provide a coarse-grain answer.

If you're talking about something which will have thousands of instances, with short lifetimes, I would guess that's probably better done with a struct rather than a class, let alone a class implementing an interface.

For something more component-like, with low numbers of instances and moderate-to-long lifetime, I can't imagine it's going to make much difference.

Answer (score 1):

IMO yes, but for a fundamental design reason far more subtle and complex than virtual dispatch or COM-like interface queries or object metadata required for runtime type information or anything like that. There is overhead associated with all of that but it depends a lot on the language and compiler(s) used, and also depends on whether the optimizer can eliminate such overhead at compile-time or link-time. Yet in my opinion there's a broader conceptual reason why coding to an interface implies (not guarantees) a performance hit:

> Coding to an interface implies that there is a barrier between you and
>   the concrete data/memory you want to access and transform.

This is the primary reason I see. As a very simple example, let's say you have an abstract image interface. It fully abstracts away its concrete details like its pixel format. The problem here is that often the most efficient image operations need those concrete details. We can't implement our custom image filter with efficient SIMD instructions, for example, if we had to `getPixel` one at a time and `setPixel` one at a time and while oblivious to the underlying pixel format.

Of course the abstract image could try to provide all these operations, and those operations could be implemented very efficiently since they have access to the private, internal details of the concrete image which implements that interface, but that only holds up as long as the image interface provides everything the client would ever want to do with an image.

Often at some point an interface cannot hope to provide every function imaginable to the entire world, and so such interfaces, when faced with performance-critical concerns while simultaneously needing to fulfill a wide range of needs, will often leak their concrete details. The abstract image might still provide, say, a pointer to its underlying pixels through a `pixels()` method which largely defeats a lot of the purpose of coding to an interface, but often becomes a necessity in the most performance-critical areas.

Just in general a lot of the most efficient code often has to be written against very concrete details at some level, like code written specifically for single-precision floating-point, code written specifically for 32-bit RGBA images, code written specifically for GPU, specifically for AVX-512, specifically for mobile hardware, etc. So there's a fundamental barrier, at least with the tools we have so far, where we cannot abstract that all away and just code to an interface without an implied penalty.

Of course our lives would become so much easier if we could just write code, oblivious to all such concrete details like whether we're dealing with 32-bit SPFP or 64-bit DPFP, whether we're writing shaders on a limited mobile device or a high-end desktop, and have all of it be the most competitively efficient code out there. But we're far from that stage. Our current tools still often require us to write our performance-critical code against concrete details.

And lastly this is kind of an issue of granularity. Naturally if we have to work with things on a pixel-by-pixel basis, then any attempts to abstract away concrete details of a pixel could lead to a major performance penalty. But if we're expressing things at the image level like, "alpha blend these two images together", that could be a very negligible cost even if there's virtual dispatch overhead and so forth. So as we work towards higher-level code, often any implied performance penalty of coding to an interface diminishes to a point of becoming completely trivial. But there's always that need for the low-level code which does do things like process things on a pixel-by-pixel basis, looping through millions of them many times per frame, and there the cost of coding to an interface can carry a pretty substantial penalty, if only because it's hiding the concrete details necessary to write the most efficient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, all the really heavy lifting when it comes to graphics is passed on to the GPU anwyay. These frees up your CPU to do other things like program flow and logic. I am not sure if there is a performance hit when programming to an interface but thinking about the nature of games, they are not something that needs to be extendable. Maybe certain classes but on the whole I wouldn't think that a game needs to programmed with extensibility in mind. So go ahead, code the implementation.

Comment: Not as much extensibility (although I could make a case for it) but testability is my main beef. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804904/xna-mock-the-game-object/828482#828482

Answer (score 0):

> it would imply a performance hit

The designer should be able to prove his opinion.